# Non-Canvas graphics in web pages

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am a complete novice at web development and I am wondering a few things about graphics rendering using JavaScript (not Flash or some other plugin). For example, is it possible to render arbitrary graphics (e.g. lines, curves, text, images etc.) inside a web page without using the Canvas feature found only in HTML5? I ask because I believe I have seen Google for example showing interactive graphics for one of their logo enhancements on their homepage for special anniversaries and the like *before* HTML5 was around and *currently* in browsers which don't even support HTML5. I also remember seeing animations in web pages during the 90s that were done in pure JavaScript.

So:

1) Is such graphics rendering possible using pure JavaScript?
2) If so, which APIs or libraries are being used?
3) Is it possible to decorate standard HTML controls with arbitrary graphics?

I am trying to determine the bounds of what is possible in a web-based UI.

Comment: Check the source on those "old" examples and figure out how they work!

Comment: Nice idea but I don't know of any that I can still access!

Comment: http://www.google.com/doodles/

Answer (score 0):

> For example, is it possible to render arbitrary graphics (e.g. lines, curves, text, images etc.) inside a web page without using the Canvas feature found only in HTML5?

Yes. Have a look at SVG, which has been around in some form or another since... 1992 or thereabouts.

There are plenty of docs and tutorials on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG).

> I ask because I believe I have seen Google for example showing interactive graphics for one of their logo enhancements on their homepage for special anniversaries and the like before HTML5 was around and currently in browsers which don't even support HTML5.

You saw SVG, which Google has used for Google doodles in the past and still uses for all sorts of stuff (portions of Google Maps on some platforms).

Comment: Thanks Simon. I know that some of what I have seen may have been done with SVG but I am not entirely convinced that it explains everything. I remember opening one web page in the 90s and seeing an animation of seveal bouncing balls flying all over the page (i.e. not confined to a SVG element) and, at the time, I remember the page stated that the animation was done in pure JavaScript. How could this have been done? Can I use JavaScript to draw graphics anywhere on the page itself such as on top of or around standard elements?

Comment: @FelixBembrick it was likely using javascript to move images around the page. So the animation was done in JS, but the images weren't.

Comment: @Mathletics is almost certainly right here. Developers have been annoying users with animated DOM elements (SVG or not) since forever.

Comment: Right, so with JavaScript I can move images around the page but there's no actual way to render arbitrary graphics outside of a specialised element such as SVG or HTML5 Canvas? Can you confirm?

Comment: @FelixBembrick correct, you cannot create arbitrary graphics with JS alone.